# Will ecto nodes be able to communicate over the network?

Tags: ros, ecto

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The ecto framework http://ecto.willowgarage.com/ looks interesting.  Do the developers plan to allow nodes to be located on different physical computers connected by a network?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/12845/will-ecto-nodes-be-able-to-communicate-over-the-network?/) by [sdavies](https://answers.ros.org/users/406/sdavies/) on ROS Answers with karma: 88 on 2012-02-01

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You can seamlessly bridge ecto graphs to ROS (see ecto_ros).

---

Originally posted by [kwc](https://answers.ros.org/users/11/kwc/) with karma: 12244 on 2012-02-01

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [jorge](https://answers.ros.org/users/1986/jorge/) on 2013-06-10**:
I see you can do it for many common ROS message types. But can I do it for custom messages?